# Бесконечный цикл при обновлении в room с использованием rxJava

Tags: android, rxjava, android-room, rxjava2, room

[image: Краткий экскурс где происходит ошибка]

Все я заккоментил, чтобы найти источник зла.

`model.updateFavorite(it)` он входит в бесконечный цикл.

Его код

```
fun updateFavorite(pokemon: PokemonEntity){
        Log.d("RefreshFavorite", pokemon.isFavorite.toString())
        pokemonsDao.update(pokemon)
    }
```

Какой метод он вызывает из Dao(room)

```
@Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    fun update(pokemon: PokemonEntity)
```

Я думаю про room лишнее, скорее всего я что-то не понимаю и сделал такую глупую ошибку, но я её не вижу.
Проблема в том, что при вызове этого метода по обновлению данных, он начинает впадать в бесконечность. И все что далее `.map` и `.subscribe` они тоже выполняются бесконечно.

Как мне решить эту проблему?

И да. Если заменить flatMap на map, ничего не изменится (проблема именно с `updateFavorite`, `model.getCardInfo(id)` отрабатывает 1 раз нормально)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по поведению у вас метод `getCardInfo` типом возвращаемого значения имеет `Flowable` или `Observable`. В таком случае вам будут приходить события каждый раз, когда меняется что-то в таблице, что вы и наблюдаете.

Чтобы это исправить - смените тип источника данных возвращаемого из метода `getCardInfo` на `Single` - он один раз получит данные и сразу завершится.